# What are self-calling functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

From what I have heard, the following is a "self-calling function":

```
func(){}();
```

How is it different from the following?

```
func(){} func();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you meant what is the difference between (*I*):

```
function(){}();
```

and (*II*):

```
function func(){};
func();
```

or even (*III*):

```
var func = function(){};
func();
```

All three behave the same in regard to the results, however they have different naming and scoping consequences:

- *I*: this will not make the function available under any name, it is run once and forgotten. You can not reference it in the future
- *II*: `func` function is created and available in the whole enclosing function, even before it is defined (*hoisting*)
- *III*: `func` variable is defined pointing to a function. It won't be accessible before being defined.

Note that in *II* and *III* the function is referencable via `func` name and can be called again multiple times. This is not possible with self-calling function in *I*.

Comment: Agreed, but then under what scenarios are self-calling functions used? I mean is there any specific need for them to be used in some sort of particular scenario?

Comment: I know this is old but for other readers: you can wrap all of your own javascript in one big self-calling function so that it runs, but you know that it won't add a variable name to the global namespace - then, no other plugins like jQuery or anything else could accidentally use the same name as yours and clash.